# The best way to make modals in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I'm looking for a modal system I can implement in my current (and future) project(s) that has a good amount of features. I would like to populate my modals with Angular components. I'm researching to make sure I choose the best option, but was wondering if anyone out in the community had some advice on this.

I have Bootstrap 3 in my project, and I understand it has a plugin for modals, but so far I've never used that. I'm not sure how well it will play with Angular components. I would like to be able to style my modals with Bootstrap themes, if possible.

Answer (score 3):

This is a Great Tool for Modals and other tools .. great for projects and works well with bootstrap. [>>ng-bootstrap<<](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal)

Answer (score 1):

**This question can have many answers.**

Finally it depends on your requirement which kind of data you want to deal with using Modal-Popup.

I'd suggest you to go with **`dynamic component`** and *make a custom modal popup* which ultimately uses bootstrap modal-popup which you can manipulate according to your requirement of the project.

**DEMO : https://plnkr.co/edit/n1my3XMtawZkO22DYjyo?p=preview**

**Yes you can make your own modal popup component which can be used across application**.

NOTE: please note there are many other ways to create the same component. This is one of them. There are various way to go with.